# Lightdm-gtk-greeter's background wallpaper is distorted in Ubuntu 12.04 (How I can correct background wallpaper errors in "lightdm-gtk-greeter"?

Tags: 12.04, unity, lightdm, desktop-background, plymouth

Changed my settings into "lightdm-gtk-greeter" to be able to select different languages at login each time I wish.

Everything is fine with my PC. It logins correctly after a while with an exception that background wallpaper is distorted as seen in the sample picture( https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS6sx.jpg )

I installed Super-Boot-Manager and using it. Is it possible that Plymouth has caused into this?

How I can correct background appearance?

Thank you in advance.

Hejar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Come to find out, the background picture defined in  /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf  did not exist anymore.  not sure how this happened, but i'd quess that my lightdm theme got messed up during an update.

I just edited that file, pointing background to an image that does exist and on reboot it was fine.  you could prolly just reinstall the lightdm theme.